# How to generate trace logs with detailed exception information?

Tags: .net, trace

I'm using XmlWriterTraceListener to write a svclog file containing all needed information to find out the reason for all possible problems - except of detailed exception information like stack trace and nested exceptions.
I already saw how you can easily browse through all the exceptions including all that helpful information, but simply passing an exception to TraceSource.TraceData doesn't work:

```
_myTrace.TraceData(TraceEventType.Error, 0, exception);
```

Edit:
[This](http://softarchitect.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/trace2.jpg) is a screenshot of the Service Trace Viewer showing a exception tree and detailed exception information.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
_myTrace.TraceData(TraceEventType.Error, 0, exception.ToString());
```

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. This is what TraceData() does anyway: Converting the data into a string.
I found a screenshot of what I meant [here](http://softarchitect.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/trace2.jpg)